# Difference in syntaxes of making objects in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, new-operator

1)What is the exact difference of the following two ways of creating an object from a class named "handler"

```
handler myhandler;
handler myhandler=new handler();
```

2) Is the following alwasy possible?

```
handler *myhandler;
handler *myhandler=new handler();
```

Comment: Is the class named handler or myhandler?

Comment: sorry, i have corrected it now

Comment: Your program should not compile.

Comment: You should read a beginner C++ tutorial. A decent one explains the differences between static and dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

```
handler myhandler;
```

That creates an object. If it's inside a function, then it has *automatic* storage duration, and will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope. If it's outside a function, then it has *static* storage duration, and will be destroyed automatically at the end of the program.

```
handler myhandler=new handler();
```

That probably doesn't compile; unless `handler` has a strange constructor allowing implicit conversion from a pointer, in which case it does something strange.

```
handler *myhandler;
```

That declares a pointer, which could be used to refer to an object of type `handler`. It doesn't create an object, nor does it point to any object yet.

```
handler *myhandler=new handler();
```

That creates a dynamic object, and initialises a pointer to point to it. This is usually a bad idea, since it's likely to lead to a *memory leak* (or worse) when you fail to delete it correctly. Don't create dynamic objects unless you really need them to outlive the current scope; and use a smart pointer when you do need to:

```
auto myhandler = std::make_unique<handler>();     // C++14
std::unique_ptr<handler> myhandler(new handler);  // C++11
```

If you really want to juggle a raw pointer for educational purposes, then remember to delete the object once you've finished with it:

```
delete myhandler;
```

and take special care to make sure this only happens once, and happens even if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that the second method is correct. The first creates a new object and then assigns a new object on top of it. I strongly recommend understanding this before proceeding:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/self-assignment-how.html

Comment: Not to mention that the first one doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should not compile as you are redefining an object in both the case.

Your first case should not compile at `new` statement as `new` returns a pointer to the newly created object unless there is a constructor taking pointer or assignment operator overloaded which takes `handler` pointer.

In the second case, it will point to newly created object.

To correct first case,

```
handler myhandler=handler();
```

provided `handler` has a default constructor or constructor with default arguments.